# What is the value of $2x+3y$ if $x+y=7$ and $x^2-y^2=21$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math

If $x+y=7$ and $x^2-y^2=21$, then what is $2x+3y$?

I solved it like this:

\begin{align}
y& =7-x \\
x^2-(7-x)^2-21&=0 \\
x^2-49+14x-x^2-21&=0 \\
14x&=70 \\
x&=5 
\end{align}

Then I solved for $y$ and I got $2$. I plugged in the values of $x$ and $y$ to $2x+3y$, and I got $16$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Has your question been answered? If yes, you should accept an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Quicker way is to note that
$$
21=(x-y)(x+y)=7(x-y)
$$
so
$$
x-y=3
$$
Combined with $x+y=7$, we get that $2x=10$ i.e. $x=5$ and $y=2$.

So your answer is correct.

Comment: thank you . that helped a lot @FoobazJohn

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** A slightly easier way.
$$x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)=7(x-y)=21 \implies x-y=3$$
But your solution is correct.

Comment: I also did that and solved for the system of $x+y=7$ and $x-y=3$ and I got $(5,2)$. Is this correct?

Comment: @harpey Yes, it is.

Comment: thank you for the help. @haris